# Manipulating srt files in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, srt

I have been trying to modify srt file (to make required adjustment in time). What i would like is to take time advancement/latency and srt files from user and manipulate that srt file with provided time shift. And save a new srt file with modified name in the same path?
How can i achieve this in plain PHP  or Codeigniter.. both will be helpful. Thank you

```
  00:12:30,332--> 00:12:45,222
  if provided input is 2 second 
   then srt file should be modified with 
    00:12:32,332 --> 00:12:47:222
```

Comment: The question is too broad. "I have been trying to modify srt file" - please, show what you've got now and where you're stuck at the moment.

Comment: I have only managed to get all file contents in string using...
$contents=file_get_contents('file_name.srt').. now i need to change all timestamp that are available in $contents.

Comment: You'll have to parse the $contents first, apply your changes & output a new file containing these changes. use the steps I just mentioned build something then ask for help if it doesn't work.without code sample your question isn't appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use library like this:

```
$subtitles = Subtitles::loadFromFile('subtitles.srt'); // load file
$subtitles->time(2); // add 2 seconds
$subtitles->save('new-subtitles-file.srt');
```

https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles